# Is the following ideal zero-dimensional?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $\left\{  p_{k}\in\mathbb{R}\left[  x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right]
:k=1,\ldots,n\right\}  $ be a family of linear polynomials such that
$p_{k}\left(  0,\ldots,0\right)  =0$. Let $\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$,
$a_{i},b_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ be scalars for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$. We define the
polynomials $f_{i}\in\mathbb{R}\left[  x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right]  $ for
$i=1,\ldots,n-1$, as follows
\begin{align*}
f_{1}  & =\alpha_{1}p_{1}^{a_{1}}-\beta_{1}p_{2}^{b_{1}}\\
f_{2}  & =\alpha_{2}p_{2}^{a_{2}}-\beta_{2}p_{3}^{b_{2}}\\
& \cdots\\
f_{n-1}  & =\alpha_{n-1}p_{n-1}^{a_{n-1}}-\beta_{n-1}p_{n}^{b_{n-1}}%
\end{align*}
Is the ideal $\left\langle f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n-1}\right\rangle $
zero dimensional?

Comment: How is the dimension of an ideal $I$ defined? The Krull dimension of the quotient?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is false.

Let $p_k=(x_1,x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,x_2+x_2+x_3)$ and all other constants
$1$. It is of dimension $1$ according to sage.